# How to add a cookies parameter to Dotdotpwn script

Tags: penetration-test

Do you know how I can add a specific cookie parameter like "access token" to dotdotpwn script?

Without this, I have that output "Web server (xxxx) didn't respond !"

Answer (score 0):

According to this [**github issue**](https://github.com/wireghoul/dotdotpwn/issues/9) `dotdotpwn` isn't designed to have a cookie option. Although you can use `-p` option to specify your payload which can be a file that contains your request which may contain cookies. You can find more info about the payload module [**here**](https://github.com/wireghoul/dotdotpwn/blob/master/EXAMPLES.txt#L79) and you can also check out some sample payload request files on the [github repository](https://github.com/wireghoul/dotdotpwn).